Differential equations where we are tryng to find a smooth space(maybe with additional structure)
Is there literature on the differential equation $TM=N$ where $M$ and $N$ are two smooth spaces (maybe with additional structure) and $T$ stands for the tangent functor?

If I understand correctly, $N$ is given and you look for $M$. This seems to be related to the Frobenius theorem. Is this the kind of result you have in mind? In that special setting you have obstructions that are encoded by an integrability condition, imposing restrictions on $N$. (There also exists infinte-dimensional versions, e.g. for Banach manifolds.)

I didn't have it in mind when I wrote the questions, but yes it is related to the Frobenius theorem.
